# Running Nvidia-docker on minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run this deep learn algorithm https://github.com/albarji/neural-style-docker that's containerized in docker pushing the image on minikube, I understand that Docker isolate the container from the machine so you can't use your GPU, that's why you use nvidia-docker but I'm not sure if you can run nvdia-docker in minikube and I don't know how to make it work.

What I'm trying to do is to run the algorithm through the minikube node to prove that the algorithm can work with a kubernetes cluster.

I managed to make the algorithm work locally with docker following the documentation and I have installed NVIDIA drivers and working on Ubuntu 18.04